# Locking mouse pointer using xGrabPointer in Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, x11, xgrabpointer

I am using `X11` to get mouse position when the mouse button is pressed in a application which runs on terminal without any window.

**Getting Mouse Position :**

```
Display *dpy;
Window root, child;
int rootX, rootY, winX, winY;
unsigned int mask;
dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
XQueryPointer(dpy,DefaultRootWindow(dpy),&root,&child,
             &rootX,&rootY,&winX,&winY,&mask);
```

Now I want to use `XGrabPointer()` to lock the mouse so that it does not interact with objects(windows , icons and docks ) present on desktop . [here](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html) is the documentation of XGrabPointer , but I don't seem to understand how to use it and what arguments to pass .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct format that seems to work for me .

```
int g=XGrabPointer(dpy,DefaultRootWindow(dpy), true, ButtonPressMask |
                 ButtonReleaseMask |
                 PointerMotionMask |
                 FocusChangeMask |
                EnterWindowMask |
                  LeaveWindowMask,GrabModeAsync,GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);
```